yolov8-segmentation.Onnx Static Quantization
I'm struggling to find the material to help me for solving my task. I'm trying to speed up the performance of YOLOv5-segmentation using static quantization. I have followed the ONNX Runtime official tutorial on how to apply static quantization.
Initially, I exported yolov8-seg.onnx.pt to the ONNX format :
import ultralytics model = YOLO('yolov8n-seg.pt') model.export(format='onnx')
Following that, I attempted to preprocess it for static quantization:
!python -m onnxruntime.quantization.preprocess --input yolov8n-seg.onnx --output yolov8n-seg-processed.onnx
However, I encountered the following error:
2024-04-11 21:05:44.0934723 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:108 onnxruntime::MergeShapeInfo] Error merging shape info for output. '/model.22/Split_output_0' source:{1,64,8400} target:{1,72,8400}. Falling back to lenient merge. 2024-04-11 21:05:44.0966858 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:108 onnxruntime::MergeShapeInfo] Error merging shape info for output. '/model.22/Split_output_1' source:{1,80,8400} target:{1,72,8400}. Falling back to lenient merge. 2024-04-11 21:05:44.1253802 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:108 onnxruntime::MergeShapeInfo] Error merging shape info for output. '/model.22/Sigmoid_output_0' source:{1,80,8400} target:{1,72,8400}. Falling back to lenient merge. 2024-04-11 21:05:44.1356836 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:108 onnxruntime::MergeShapeInfo] Error merging shape info for output. 'output0' source:{1,116,8400} target:{1,108,8400}. Falling back to lenient merge.
I have limited experience with ONNX and quantization, and I'm still in the early stages of learning. Therefore, I don't possess extensive knowledge about resolving these errors. I would greatly appreciate your help !
